# Error that the executable window does not appear and there is no error

Tags: c#, winforms

There was an error not only that the execution window did not appear, but also that nothing appeared in the error window. I searched for the cause by annotating it. The equal function made a mistake, and I don't know why.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)         
        {

            do
            {
                randQuestion = r.Next(0, 5);

            }
            while (equal(beforeQ, randQuestion));

            randQuestion = r.Next(0, 5);

            for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
            {

                do
                {
                    randBogi = r.Next(1, 5);
                }
                while (equal(beforeB, randBogi));

                beforeB[j - 1] = randBogi;
                R_Question[i, j] = Question[randQuestion, randBogi];
            }
        }

        bool equal(int[] before, int rand)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < before.Length ; k++)
            {
                if (before[k].Equals(rand))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: use before[k] == rand

Comment: k < before.Length - 1; - are you sure you need the -1, when you're using the "less-than" operator?

Comment: I added a '-1' and ran it, but if you get rid of it, I'll get the error I told you. The text was edited out of '-1'.

Comment: Even if you insert '=', the same error occurs as mentioned above.

Comment: "same error" doesn't help us help you when you don't describe the error.  The code is wrong anyway, get ahead by googling "c# random shuffle".

Comment: You Equal function rather performs a 'Contains'. Maybe this is intended, but the name is confusing, since an array and an int can nether be equal.